# DrawInstanced versus DrawIndexed and mixing them together

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

Let say i have a complex object with many vertices and i'd like to draw many instances of this object. I'm wondering which method would be faster: one DrawInstanced or many DrawIndexed. Also which would be faster if i'd have very simple object, let say sprite with 4 vertices, and i'd like to draw hundreds of them? What i mean? I mean that DrawInstanced is a bit like Draw - sometimes it puts the same vertex in VertexShader many times. For example sprite has 4 vertices but with triangle list topology two of them will be processed twice and with DrawInstanced they would be precessed only once. Ofc with more complex objects this problem grows and that's why i asked for solution and yours opinions.

Second part of my question. So, if there is a problem with processing the same vertices many times then maybe there is a way to mix DrawInstanced with indexing or sth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indexing and instancing at the same time, there is no need to choose between them.  Indexing reduces the amount of vertices that must be supplied to the GPU by reusing them.  Instancing is a performance enhancement which allows you to quickly draw the same geometry multiple times in a frame.

Comment: Ok, that's good information! Could you give me a quick sample how to mix these two drawing methods? It could be even a simple pseudo code. I would be glad

Comment: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter03.html this is a good resource on hardware instancing and includes index buffers